# How to create a WordPress gallery with videos, and allow sharing in Facebook

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a WordPress gallery by modifying the default WP gallery for images. It also includes a share/send to Facebook option.

Now I want to create a same gallery but instead with .mp4 files.
But there is no option of to create a gallery with .mp4 format in wordpress. Can anyone suggest how it can be done please.

Update:
Default WordPress gallery only accept images. I want it to accept .mp4 as well.

[image]

Comment: goo.gl/qUA5Fd  ...

Comment: here's the link to my image gallery

Comment: sorry i cant see your code

Comment: Its the default wordress gallary, I just want it to accept .mp4 format

Answer (score 0):

> [Cool Video Gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cool-video-gallery/) is a Video Gallery plugin for WordPress with
>   option to upload videos, attach media files, add Youtube videos and
>   manage them in multiple galleries. Automatic preview image generation
>   for uploaded videos using FFMPEG library available. Option provided to
>   upload images for video previews. **Supports ‘.flv’, ‘.mp4’, ‘.mov’,
>   ‘.m4v’ and ‘.mp3’** video files presently.

Comment: thanks for this plugin. But I would like to make some modification to default WP/theme files to achieve this if possible. - too many plugins are making it slow.